# how do I use a variable content as an argument for vim command?

Tags: vim

for example suppose I did

```
:let foo=pattern
```

and now I want to perform `Ggrep patter` but use variable `foo` instead of the literal `patter` string.

```
:echo foo
```

outputs `pattern`, but

```
:Ggrep foo
```

just looks for foo

UPDATE:

building a string of command and then running :execute on it is not a solution, its a hack.  And it breaks with any non-trivial variable values.

Comment: what is `Ggrep` (capital G?)?

Comment: git grep from 'fugutive' vim plugin

Comment: example command is wrong. it should be let foo='pattern'. Say that :execute is a hack is totally wrong. That's the solution: You want vim to evaluate the command before execute it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not about variable but maybe vim abbreviate command can helps.
Try from command line:

```
:abbreviate foo pattern
```

Then

```
:Ggrep foo<space>
```

It will complete 'foo' to your 'pattern'.

Comment: Now try to run `echo foo`. Opps `echo pattern` which is not a variable. this is a hack and misguiding.

Answer (score 11):

what about:

```
:execute ':grep ' . foo
```

Comment: how do I properly escape foo's content? it might contain special characters like ", ', /, \, etc

Comment: @Vitaly Kushner: See ":help escape()" and ":help fnameescape()".

Comment: I know escape(), but not sure about what characters to escape

Comment: fnameescape() is not good, its not a filename argument, its an arg to plugin function. suppose I
   :let foo = "aaa\"bbbb'cccc"

Comment: i think that 'how to escape a regular expression bullet-proof in vim' is another question, either here or on stackoverflow.com.

Comment: not really. what you proposed is a kind of 'eval' expression, which *cab* work, but once your variable contains anything slightly more interesting then [a-z] it breaks. So the question is still pending: How do you call a plugin function passing variable as an argument.

Comment: well, read the 'fugitive.vim': call s:command("-bang -nargs=? -complete=customlist,s:EditComplete Ggrep :execute s:Grep(<bang>0,<q-args>)")
call s:command("-bar -bang -nargs=* -complete=customlist,s:EditComplete Glog :execute s:Log('grep<bang>',<f-args>)")

they use 'execute' to actually call the function 'Grep' (that's visible only inside that script). otherwise you could use 'call', but since that function is not visible to the global scope: bad luck. either change the script or live with 'the hack'.

Comment: yes, but they run execute with a special expansions like <bang> and <q-args>.

Comment: <q-args> is actually interesting here. try :h <q-args> :


"If the first two characters of an escape sequence are "q-" (for example,
<q-args>) then the value is quoted in such a way as to make it a valid value
for use in an expression.  This uses the argument as one single value."

so there IS a way to quote stuff when defining a user command. What I'm looking for is the same for when I'm runing :exec, or similar.

Comment: soo .. building a string to `:execute` actually _is_ the solution :)

Comment: it might, if it "is quoted in such a way as to make it a valid value for use in an expression" ;).

Comment: I am pulling my hair out over this too. You can't issue a command like `let xyz = tabpagenr()` then `tabnext xyz`. Vim's scripting language is as flawed as its modal environment is flawless.

Comment: I can't get this to work for a command that requires a range, because ":execute" gives "No range allowed"

Answer (score 2):

If you don't like the `:exe` solution, you can "read" the contents of a variable into to the command line by using the `=` expression register.  For example, type `:Ggrep` then press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>r</kbd> and then type `=foo` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>. Assuming the variable `foo` contained "pattern", your command line should now look like:

```
:Ggrep pattern
```

This has the advantage that you can see the actual command that will be run, and even modify it before pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd> a second time.

See:

```
:help "=
```

Answer (score 2):

As far as I'm aware, there is no option other than `:execute`

```
echo "hello"

" same as

let greeting = "hello"
execute "echo '" . greeting . "'"
```

However, as you've noticed, if the variable contains certain bad characters, that causes an issue:

```
let greeting = "hel'lo"
execute "echo '" . greeting . "'"

" hel
" E121: Undefined variable: lo
```

To avoid this, the string variable needs to be escaped properly. This is actually easier than it sounds, using single-quoted strings. Double-quoted strings would be a nightmare, but if you look at `:help literal-string` it says:

> Note that single quotes are used. This string is taken as it is.  No backslashes are removed or have a special meaning.  The only exception is that two quotes stand for one quote.

So the only special character is `'`, which can be escaped by replacing it with `''`. That can be done with `substitute`.

```
let greeting = "hel'lo"
execute "echo '" . substitute(greeting, "'", "''", 'g') . "'"
" echoes: hel'lo
```

That's a bit gross looking, so you could move that into a function:

```
function! EscapeVimStr(str)
  return "'" . substitute(a:str, "'", "''", 'g') . "'"
endfunction

let greeting = "hel'lo"
execute 'echo' EscapeVimStr(greeting)
" echoes: hel'lo
```

Answer (score 2):

#### Make it an environment variable!

Given:

```
:let $foo="whatever"
```

This command

```
:e $foo
```

edits the file `whatever` because Vim recognizes `$` in commands and expands it. You must escape the dollar sign if you want it literal.

Comment: this is IMO the actual solution that works in vim scripts as well. thank you so much.